# Use of Flyway with RCP built from Eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, flyway

We have an RCP application built from many individual plug-ins that save and restore application data to a single, user-selectable database made up of several tables. Over time the database format changes and we want to be able to manage these changes by using Flyway database migration.

One solution would be to have each plugin performing its own migration (i.e. call Flyway.migrate in each plugin) however this has the disadvantage that if tables in the database are shared by more than one plugin then ordering the execution order of the migrate calls between plug-ins becomes key and problematic.

A better solution would be to have a single Migrate call but the problem then becomes how to feed the classpaths of the Java migration scripts to the Flyway instance especially given that due to the lazy loading of the Eclipse plug-ins classes with the migration code required may not yet have been loaded. This is not a problem for SQL based migration scripts as the API supports this - it does not support it for classpath based searching.

The question then is there a way to ensure that when Flyway.migrate() is called from a single plug-in all the classpaths of migration scripts are discoverable by the flyway scanner classes?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Each Eclipse plugin has its own separate classpath containing only its dependencies. You can't find things in other plugins using classpaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of problem is usually solved with [extension points and extensions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_are_extensions_and_extension_points%3F) in RCP/plug-in based applications.

For example, the migration plug-in could define an extension point `migrationScript` that is able to specify the SQL code to migrate the database schema. Then individual plug-ins are free to contribute migrations scripts to this extension.

```
<extension point="org.example.migrationScript">
  <script sql="alter table ..." />
</extension>
```

At runtime, the migration plug-in can use the [IExtensionRegistry](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_registry.htm) to read all `migrationScript` extensions. The RCP runtime ensures that extensions from all installed plug-ins are read and activates contributing plugins as necessary (e.g. if their code is invoked).

If the migration requires Java code to be contributed, the migration plug-in can define an interface or abstract class for which the contributing plug-ins can provide concrete implementations.

For example, the migration plugin defines this interface:

```
interface ScriptProvider {
  String sql();
}
```

... and individual plug-ins contribute their share to the migration

```
<extension point="org.example.migrationScript">
  <script class="org.example.MyScriptProvider" />
</extension>
```

```
public class MyScriptProvider {
  public String sql() { return "alter table ..."; }
}
```

The classpath and activation of necessary plug-ins are managed by the RCP runtime and OSGi respectively.

Comment: Thanks - had sort of come to that conclusion - although this is still problamatic if want to use a java class to provide the migration contribution; as greg-449 says the classpaths are localised to each plugin/bundle so that you end up having to create an uber classpath loader that manages the loaders from all contributing bundles - and that's before you get into problems with OsgiClassPathLocationScanner and having to prepend classpaths with "bin/"

Comment: You don't need to - and you should not - manage the classpath manually. Please see my edited answer.